# Complete missing values in time series using previous day data - using R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, missing-data

I have a data frame where each row is a different date and every column is different time series.
The date range in the table is 01.01.2019-01.01.2021.
Some of the time series are relevant for only part of the dates and have missing values on weekends and holidays.

How can I complete the missing values for each time series using previous day values only for the relevant dates of each column (if the time series in a specific column is from 01.03.2019 to 01.09.2019 I want to complete only the missing values in this dates range)?

I have tried to use the fill function:

```
data <- data %>%  
fill(colnames(data))
```

but it completes also the missing data after the specific time series is over.

For example, the df is:

```
#  Date         time_series_1           time_series_2
1  01-01-2019               NA                      10
2  02-01-2019               5                       NA 
3  03-01-2019               10                      NA 
4  04-01-2019               20                      6 
5  05-01-2019               30                      NA 
6  06-01-2019               NA                      8 
7  07-01-2019               7                       NA 
8  08-01-2019               5                       NA 
9  09-01-2019               NA                      NA
10 10-01-2019               NA                      NA
```

The desired output is:

```
#  Date         time_series_1           time_series_2
1  01-01-2019               NA                      10
2  02-01-2019               5                       10 
3  03-01-2019               10                      10 
4  04-01-2019               20                      6 
5  05-01-2019               30                      6 
6  06-01-2019               30                      8 
7  07-01-2019               7                       NA 
8  08-01-2019               5                       NA 
9  09-01-2019               NA                      NA
10 10-01-2019               NA                      NA
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the trick is that you want to fill downward except for the bottommost NAs. And the problem with `tidyr`'s `fill` is that it goes all the way down.

This isn't a fully-tidyverse solution, but for this data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data <- tribble(
  ~Date, ~time_series_1, ~time_series_2,
  as.Date("2019-01-01"), NA, 10,
  as.Date("2019-02-01"), 5, NA,
  as.Date("2019-03-01"), 10, NA,
  as.Date("2019-04-01"), 20, 6,
  as.Date("2019-05-01"), 30, NA,
  as.Date("2019-06-01"), NA, 8,
  as.Date("2019-07-01"), 7, NA,
  as.Date("2019-08-01"), 5, NA,
  as.Date("2019-09-01"), NA, NA,
  as.Date("2019-10-01"), NA, NA
)
```

You can determine the ending date for each time series separately:

```
LastTS1Date <- with( data, max(Date[!is.na(time_series_1)])) 
LastTS2Date <- with( data, max(Date[!is.na(time_series_2)]))
```

And then use baseR filter syntax to only change the part of the data frame that goes up to those dates:

```
data[data$Date <= LastTS1Date,] <-
  data[data$Date <= LastTS1Date,] %>% fill(time_series_1)

data[data$Date <= LastTS2Date,] <-
  data[data$Date <= LastTS2Date,] %>% fill(time_series_2)
```